# How do I protect my password on the website?

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

On the site, the login is made using a code of the type if the entered password matches the variable in which the password is stored, then the person enters the site. How to protect the site from the magic F12 button? I.e. how to make the password impossible to find
out

p.s. I have never done anything like this so the experience is 0.

I wrote the code and don't know how to protect passwords.

```
function checkUsernamePassword() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    if (username == "admin" && password == "12345") {
        window.location = "../index.html";
    }
    else {
        window.location = "invalid-login.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, you've to store the credentials on your server and check them at server.

Comment: What was your prior research on "how to safely and properly handle passwords"?

Comment: @Teemu if you use encryption, then you can't access the protected data without knowledge of the password. So you can do a client-side password check if encryption is used that requires the password to decrypt the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily, your approach would be easily bypassed.

However, with the WebCrypto API you can use strong encryption to protect the data that needs to be accessed with a password.

You'd use a salted PBKDF2 to stretch the password into a symmetric encryption key. Then, the data can only be accessed when the correct password is entered.

This approach relies on the password being of sufficient entropy to prevent a brute-force attack.

Comment: Now, we take a look at the code, and copy-paste the redirection URL to the addressbar and hit enter, the server has no clue were the correct credentials given or not, it just sends the page as requested. It's as simple as _never_ verify passwords at client. Everything you send to the server can be spoofed.

Comment: @Teemu oh for sure, the OP's approach was a catastrophe. However, modern end-to-end encryption is gaining popularity as a legitimate approach to allowing data to never be visible in non-encrypted form to the server, which can only be decrypted using a password that never leaves the client.